# apply configured wordpress theme / plugins to multiple websites

Tags: php, mysql, linux, wordpress, multisite

I am wondering if there is an ability to apply my configured custom wordpress cms theme that I customized, and configured *(including use of several plugins)* and apply this completed configured theme to multiple domains or websites through a shared hosting - without going in one by one installing and re-configuring the theme? over an over again.

Is there a quicker **way to apply my theme and it's plugins across multiple websites / domains of shared hosting without installing Wordpress -> Applying the theme -> re-configuring everything -> installing / setting plugins etc. If the content does not matter *initially*? All I want is my Wordpress theme / websites pushed across about dozen of my other domains** within shared hosting environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this plugin https://sr.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/ It will transfer everything, all your settings, all your files. It will automatically change the links to the new url if you have some hardcoded. It will also transfer the database. All you need to do on the target domains/hostings is to install a new WP instance and connect it to the database and then import using this. There might be more refined solutions to this, but this one is very effective and quick to utilize.